# Cinema Booking System with C#

Tags: c#

I am building a cinema booking system with C# using Visual Studio. The main code I have designed for the program is shown below, absent the classes I have created to hold film, screen, customer, and showing data.

```
namespace Glosflix
{
    public partial class NewBooking : Form
    {
        public List<Film> filmList = new List<Film>();
        public List<Showing> showingList = new List<Showing>();
        public NewBooking()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            filmList.Add(new Film("Ida", 90, "15", "A young novitiate discovers the fate that befell her Jewish parents during the Nazi occupation of Poland."));
            filmList.Add(new Film("Leviathan", 147, "15", "Modern retelling of Job, set in the Barents Sea."));
            filmList.Add(new Film("Grand Budapest Hotel", 100, "15", " A hotel concierge inherits a fortune from an aristocrat, and the wrath of her disappointed heirs."));
            Screen screenA = new Screen(250, "1");
            Screen screenB = new Screen(150, "2");
            Screen screenC = new Screen(120, "3");
            showingList.Add(new Showing(512, screenA, filmList[0], "9:00"));
            showingList.Add(new Showing(612, screenA, filmList[0], "15:00"));
            showingList.Add(new Showing(712, screenB, filmList[1], "10:00"));
            showingList.Add(new Showing(812, screenB, filmList[1], "16:00"));
            showingList.Add(new Showing(912, screenC, filmList[2], "12:00"));
            showingList.Add(new Showing(412, screenC, filmList[2], "21:00"));
            Customer customerA = new Customer(5238, "Thomas Stearns");
            cmbTickets.Items.Add(1);
            cmbTickets.Items.Add(2);
            cmbTickets.Items.Add(3);
            cmbTickets.Items.Add(4);
            cmbTickets.Items.Add(5);
            cmbTickets.Items.Add(6);
            cmbTickets.Items.Add(7);
            cmbTickets.Items.Add(8);
            cmbTickets.Items.Add(9);
            cmbTickets.Items.Add(10);


        }

        private void NewBooking_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Film i in filmList)
                cmbFilm.Items.Add(i.getTitle());
        }

        private void cmbFilm_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmbShowing.Items.Clear();
            String filmTitle = cmbFilm.SelectedItem.ToString();

            foreach (Showing i in showingList)
            {
                if (filmTitle.Equals(i.getFilm().getTitle()))
                {
                  cmbShowing.Items.Add(i.getTime());

                }
            }

            cmbShowing.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void btnBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cmbShowing.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a film and showing.");
            }
            else if (cmbTickets.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select the number of tickets required.");

            }


        }

    }
}
```

In the code, to make a booking the user interacts with a combobox holding the titles of all available films. This loads all of the showing times associated with the film in a separate combobox. A final combobox holds the values 1 to 10, in which the user chooses the number of tickets they require for their booking.

I want when the user clicks on the book button on the program's interface, all of the information about the showing is displayed in a listbox, based on the information that the user has entered in the interface's comboboxes. I'd also like the program to calculate the total cost of the booking based on the number of tickets the user has selected, and display this in the combobox.

I assume that the best way to implement this would be to create a booking class with a method contained inside it that would multiply the seat number entered with the cost of a cinema ticket, to produce an overall booking cost. How do I go about this?

Comment: You said you wanted to create a Booking class with the code to multiply the number of seats by the unit cost. What exactly are you unsure about?

Comment: Is that the right way to do this? Also am I to use the selection that the user has made in the showing combobox, so that all information related to the showing can be displayed in the listtable on the user interface?

Comment: That is a design question then. Would it be a sensible solution? Probably. Would it be "the right thing" to do in your case? I don't know, it depends on large amounts of contextual information that it missing from your post, such as what would you want to do with the booking information. A business application will likely want to send it over to a database, call some payment processing service, etc., so a Booking class with all required information is likely to be useful. A teaching assignment might have very different constraints, though.

Comment: I also don't understand exactly how the selection made in the comboboxes could be used to return all the information related to the chosen film and showing. I wondered if anybody knew of any examples of program code that accomplished this that I could look.

Comment: Your code is already retrieving the information on the selected film when it queries the ComboBox.SelectedIndex property. You can use either that or SelectedItem to find out what the user wants to watch, etc. Then you create a new instance of your Booking class just like you create instances of Film in your example. You might assist want to look at the documentation of ComboBox and its data binding properties (DataSource, ValueMember, SelectedValue, etc.) as they could make your life easier.